# Run windows command

Tags: windows, command-line

(Moved the question here from StackOverflow)

I am not familiar with windows. Please help with the following questions.

1. The windows program is "xxx.exe". When running it, we can do "xxx -options" instead of "xxx.exe -options". Is it true for all windows command that "xxx" and "xxx.exe" both work? If so, I can do "xxx -options" across platforms as linux and mac have "xxx" instead of "xxx.exe".
2. If I run the command with the absolute path and the path contains spaces, I understand that the path needs to be surrounded by quotation marks in windows. Is it right?

Thanks!

Comment: 1/ Yes. 2/ Yes. However, many Windows programs use a `/` to indicate an option instead of `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Windows knows what the `.exe` extension is.  Therefore it is not necessary to type `.exe` when executing an application. So `xxx.exe` and `xxx` are identical.  So you can use `xxx -options` without issues.  As DavidPostill pointed out, some programs use `/` or `-` as switch options, it is program specific and not universal.

The answer to your second question, that is a little harder.  In some cases you will need to double qoute (`"`) the path, if it has spaces.  In other cases, you do not.  This will depend on the version of Windows you are using.  I *believe* since Windows Vista, Windows will recognize spaces in File Explorer and other Windows applications without issue.  So running `c:\example folder\xxx -option` will work on modern systems.  There are always exceptions.  In the end, if it doesnt work, double quote the path and it will always work.